# Robocopy, How to exclude all files except one

Tags: azure, robocopy

I have setup an Azure pipeline, that runs on an op-premises agent, that performs [Windows Machine File Copy task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops), which uses Robocopy to copy files from my computer to a remote server.

The copied files are a .net core application.

1. I am adding a file `app_offline.htm` to stop new incoming trafic using `Windows Machine File Copy task`
2. I am copying all the application files to the destination using the `Windows Machine File Copy task`
3. I am trying to remove the `app_offline.htm` using `Windows Machine File Copy task` this time using `/Purge`

As i read using `/Purge` checks `source` and `destination` folders for differencies and deletes the extra files or folders in the `destination`

In the 3 step:
How can i exclude all the files from the copy operation and using `/Purge` it will find that only the `app_offline.htm` file is not in the source folder and deleting it from `destination`

I am using e.g:`/xf appsettings.json` to exclude one file from copying, is there a way to exclude everything except one file.

There is no `Delete File` task in Azure pipelines regarding the remote server and using Powershell is restricted from firewall rules.

Thanks

Comment: Using ```/PURGE /XF *``` doesnt delete the ```app_offline.html```

Answer (score 1):

I figured in out by adding `app_offline.htm /Purge`

It deletes the file since it is not found in the source and doesnt copy the rest of the files again